# Knockout foreach binding not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

I have a knockout foreach loop that works fine in Chrome but is erroring out in IE8.

The following is the binding:

```
<ul>
<!-- ko foreach: { data: tasks, as: 'task' } -->
    <!-- ko if: somecondition -->
        <li data-bind="css: { active: somthing }">
            <a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#someID">Text <span data-bind="text: task.tasks().length - 1" class="someclass"></span></a>
        </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: someOtherCondition -->
        <li data-bind="css: { active: somthing }">
            <a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#someOtherID">Text <span data-bind="text: task.tasks().length - 1" class="someclass"></span></a>
        </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

IE8 says the following:

```
Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: 'task' is undefined;
Bindings value: test: task.tasks().length - 1
```

EDIT: Just had a new development. It seems as if when I do the foreach loop not containerless it works. In other words, if I do the following, it works:

```
<ul>
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: tasks, as: 'task' }">
    <!-- ko if: somecondition -->
        <li data-bind="css: { active: somthing }">
            <a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#someID">Text <span data-bind="text: task.tasks().length - 1" class="someclass"></span></a>
        </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: someOtherCondition -->
        <li data-bind="css: { active: somthing }">
            <a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#someOtherID">Text <span data-bind="text: task.tasks().length - 1" class="someclass"></span></a>
        </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
</ul>
```

Maybe that gives more information into what's going wrong?

Any ideas?

Comment: You could just do the foreach on ul element,you don't need that extra virtual binding.

Comment: From the Knockout code "(IE <= 8 or IE 9 quirks mode parses your HTML weirdly, treating closing `</li>` tags as if they don't exist, thereby moving comment nodes that are direct descendants of `<ul>` into the preceding `<li>`)". It has code to try to fix this, but it may not be working in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The second example you are showing shouldn't work either because it is semantically incorrect.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: tasks, as: 'task' }">
    <li>
        <!-- ko if: somecondition -->
            <div data-bind="css: { active: somthing }">
                <a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#someID">Text <span data-bind="text: task.tasks().length - 1" class="someclass"></span></a>
            </div >
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: $index() === 1 && $root.showGroupTasks() -->
            <div data-bind="css: { active: somthing }">
                <a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#someOtherID">Text <span data-bind="text: task.tasks().length - 1" class="someclass"></span></a>
            </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

Place your containerless binding inside the li so that IE8 recognizes it properly, and then use a containerless binding or div's or something to ensure cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I figured out another solution while working at it more and I don't want to accept this answer because I didn't test it out so I don't want to be misleading to others possibly

Answer (score 0):

Please see PW Kad's answer for a possibly more elegant and semantically correct way of doing it. I didn't want to accep that answer because I didn't test it out.

I figured out a solution that worked:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: tasks, as: 'task' }">
    <li data-bind="if: somecondition, css: { active: somthing }">
        <a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#someID">Text <span data-bind="text: task.tasks().length - 1" class="someclass"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li data-bind="if: someOtherCondition, css: { active: somthing }">
        <a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#someOtherID">Text <span data-bind="text: task.tasks().length - 1" class="someclass"></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that you have multiple LI's for each item in the observable array, and therefore if you use this and put any styling on the LI it will not look right.

Comment: @PWKad very true. But the LIs are actually not showing up unless the index in the array is a certain index. This isn't a very general way of doing it but it's what the project requires and the styling takes that into consideration. I was just trying to figure out why the containerless bindings didn't work in IE8 and I think you explained that IE8 was getting confused by my semantics.